# How do I rotate an object using transform.forward taking into account the surface normal?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a tank that is supposed to move up a hill. I would like the tank to move parallel to the slope.

[My current problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YcFZ.png)

[My desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joNLW.png)

This problem has to do with the way I am rotating the tank, which is by transform.forward.

```
Vector3 newCoords = camera.TransformDirection(moveDirection.x, 0, moveDirection.y);

transform.forward = new Vector3(newCoords.x, 0f, newCoords.z);
```

`moveDirection` is the Vector2 from the controller's joystick. `camera.TransformDirection` is basically making the forward of the tank, the forward of the camera. I'm not exactly sure but `transform.forward` is somehow resetting one of the axes, which doesn't allow it on the surface.

My question is how do I rotate the tank using `transform.forward` while keeping the tank parallel to the slope at all times?

*If you need any clarification please ask. Thank you for reading, help would be greatly appreciated!*

Answer (score 0):

You can try two different solutions:

1. Use a rigidbody and you don't have to do nothing.
2. You probably have to calculate angle between the tank and the ground.
   For doing this, you have to use a raycast (or spherecast,boxcast,...):

```cs
RaycastHit slopeHit;
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out slopeHit, raycastLength))
{
float angleBetween = Vector3.Angle(slopeHit.normal, Vector3.up);
}
```

Try implement it and use angle returned for modify the angle of your tank.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments. Please close the question and mark my or your answer as correct